# How do I make a macOS button become highlighted (blue)?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsbutton

I've tried this:

```
myButton.highlight(true)
```

But this only turns the button into a darker blue, which is the "pressed down" state of the button.

Also, the button won't work when I press enter on my keyboard.

How can I make the button highlighted(blue) and togglable when I press enter?

Comment: Do you mean `drawFocusRingMask()`? I don't see any `focusRing` property

Comment: Neither `.default` nor `.exterior` works.

Comment: That won't do either but I've just seen this in the focusRingType description: "Changing the value in this property does not cause the view to draw the actual focus ring. You are responsible for drawing the focus ring in your view’s draw(_:) method whenever your view is made the first responder." Any idea how that works?

Comment: Do you mean the default button? Set the key equivalent to Enter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Interface Builder, select your button. Then in the sidebar, click on the Identity Inspector and set your button's **Keyboard Equivalent** to the Return key.

[image: identity inspector]